# The meaning of "Not but what it might have been for something else; but it warn't."?

Tags: meaning, expressions, literature, charles-dickens

What exactly does this line by Dickens mean?

> "'Yes, master, and I've never been in it much.' (I had come out of Kingston Jail last on a vagrancy committal. **Not but what it might have been for something else; but it warn't.**)"
>
> *[Great Expectations](https://books.google.it/books?id=ONIoAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA271&lpg=PA271&dq=%22come%20out%20of%20Kingston%20Jail%20last%20on%20a%20vagrancy%20committal%22&source=bl&ots=p7VQsLG3ze&sig=XNZncSirYE0QDueBL1XDNg8ESXs&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22come%20out%20of%20Kingston%20Jail%20last%20on%20a%20vagrancy%20committal%22&f=false)*, chapter 42, Magwitch to Pip and Herbert

I'm not sure about the meaning of the second sentence.

Comment: 'Not that it couldn't [equally well] have been for some other offence ...'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Not but what](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/not_but_what)** is another way of saying *Nevertheless*.

> #### Nevertheless
>
> - in spite of what has just been said

([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nevertheless))

So, instead, the sentence could read:

> "I had come out of Kingston Jail last on a vagrancy committal. **Nevertheless** it might have been for something else; but it warn't."

Which means that, despite what was just said, the speaker could've been in jail for something else, but wasn't.